# Trouble when getting ARCore image frame to feed QRCode Scanner

Tags: android, graphics, arcore

Ive been building app using ARCore, let user to scan QRCode and render the 3D object respectively. I tried using AugmentedImage for recognizing QRCode but it doesn't work well because the difference of QR Codes is not really significant for ARCore to recognize one by one.

I want to integrate QRCode Scanner (using ZXing lib or Google Vision API) to ARCore in one module, take advantage of ARCore frame.

https://github.com/google-ar/sceneform-android-sdk/issues/43
I tried this but when I process grayscale, it went to a trouble that the buffer is not large enough.... Please help!

My code:

```
@Override
public void onUpdate(FrameTime frameTime) {
    // delegate this frame to cloud session to process
    if (this.cloudSession != null) {
        this.cloudSession.processFrame(mSceneView.getArFrame());
    }

    Frame frame = mSceneView.getArFrame();
    if (null == frame) return;
    try (Image image = frame.acquireCameraImage()) {
        if (image.getFormat() != ImageFormat.YUV_420_888) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "Expected image in YUV_420_888 format, got format " + image.getFormat());
        }

        ByteBuffer processedImageBytesGrayscale =
                edgeDetector.detect(
                        image.getWidth(),
                        image.getHeight(),
                        image.getPlanes()[0].getRowStride(),
                        image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer());

        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(),
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        processedImageBytesGrayscale.rewind();
        bitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(processedImageBytesGrayscale);


        String code = QRCodeHelper.detectQRCode(this, bitmap);
        if (code != null) {
            runOnUiThread(() -> tvScanningResult.setText(code));
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception copying image", e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap
image.getWidth(),
image.getHeight(),
Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
```

try

```
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                image.getWidth(),
                image.getHeight(),
                Bitmap.Config.ALPHA_8);
```